# How to disable a user's account in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My website needs to be able to "disable" or "de-activate" a user's account  (as per the user's request, of course). Actually, the link I put in my website is to delete the account completely.

But, from experience, I know that it is simply good practice to never completely erase a user's account from your database.  It's best to simply disable it somehow, so the user can no longer log-in.  But, the account itself should remain in the database archives, for various obvious reasons.

And, therein lies my dilemma. I know how to delete an account using my PHP code (a simple MySQL `DELETE` query is all that's needed). This is easy.

However, I have no idea how to disable/deactivate an account in a MySQL database, so that the user is no longer able to log into my website. Extensive online searches have yielded nothing.

The only thing I was able to find was something about: `REVOKE PRIVILEGES for user  "login"` etc.

But, I wasn't surprised when this did not work. It's only server-side.  It's not possible to revoke privileges that were never granted in the first place.

Any idea what sort of code I would need to disable/de-activate a user's account in PHP?

Comment: Add a column to the user table call 'active' which can either be true or false. Check this column when logging in. Set it to false when disabling the account.

Comment: Are we talking about MySQL accounts or your website's accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, add a row "activated" to your login table (I call it now "login").

**"Delete" an account (or just disable) )**

Something like this? I don't know if you work with id's. I would recommend it.

```
<?php

$userid = $_SESSION["userid"]; // SET USER ID for example by session

if($_POST["delete"])
{
 mysqli_query($conn, mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "UPDATE login SET activated = 'no' WHERE id = '$userid'"));
 // Do other stuff
}

?>
```

**Check if account's activated**

On login, you check first if the username and the passwords are right and only **THEN** you have to check if the account's activated. Use something like this:

```
$activated = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND activated = 'yes'")));
```

$activated will be 1 if the user's is activated. So, before setting a session (or whatever)

```
if($activated == 1)
{
  // your stuff
}
```

Code is untested, but should work. If it doesn't work ask for additional help in the comments.

**Edit:** Never safe passwords as plain text! Use md5 (still unsecure) or use hashing. [Hashing on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) Thanks to halfer

Comment: Your SQL may risk unauthorised injection if you use concatenation like that, and implies that passwords should be stored as plain text. Use parameter binding and hashing respectively (or at least make that clear in your answers, so an unsuspecting OP does not add security vulnerabilities into their work).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, this is what I needed.  A separate column to the table, which would have a boolean value.  However, please, could you specify the correct syntax before Session_start()  :  <? PHP          IF ACTIVATED = "1"   { session_start();     is this correct?

Comment: Attention! If you use a boolean value you have to change the if statement. Use a string value and check if it's yes or no (how I did). This would be correcht: `<?php session_start(); if($activated == 1) { $_SESSION["user"] = $username; } ?>` You don't HAVE TO set this like I. Check on every page where the user needs to be logged in if the session user is set (`if($_SESSION["user]) // stuff `) @newuserphp

Comment: Eek, that's not how to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`! You've fed the whole query into it, but you should only feed in parameters. If a parameter contains a dangerous character (e.g. an apostrophe) it will be correctly escaped, so that it is not treated as a string delimiter. However the quotes in the query itself you _do_ want to treat as string delimiters, so it is important not to escape them. Do something like `"UPDATE login SET activated = 'no' WHERE id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $userid) . "'"`.

Comment: MD5 is not good for the purpose of password hashing - `hash_password()` is generally recommended instead (because it is slow, and because it is automatically salted).

Comment: @Baldoius :  thanks for your help.  The "idea" itself worked in theory.  But, when I tried to test in on my PHP code, I kept getting the error :  "variable LOGIN not defined.  I know what this means;  for some reason, my code cannot see the $login variable which I defined.  I have no idea why this is so, especially as I am using :  PHP  SESSION_START(), on each page,  starting with the INDEX.PHP file.

Comment: U have to set the session login if a user login was successfull @newuserphp

Comment: Please elaborate :   how do i do that?  I already set the session login on the INDEX.PHP,  which is the first file.  After that,  I simply put "PHP  session_start()"  on every following php file.  But, each time I try to log in,  it tells me :  variable not defined  :((

Comment: You have to set the session_start before you are setting the session. Thank you for accepting @newuserphp

Answer (score 3):

I typically add a `deleted_at` field to tables that might have deleted columns: that way, you still have the data, but it's deactivated, per se. If you want to delete a field, you set that `deleted_at` to current timestamp. Then, when pulling data, check if that `deleted_at` field IS NOT NULL, and you'll know if it's deactivated or not.